# Inconsistent behavior with drag-and-drop of network files in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I see an odd behavior in JavaFX that I can't seem to explain or know how to resolve. My application involves importing files for processing. Users can either drag-and-drop files into the application, or use a standard *browse* dialog to select the files they want to import.

Our clients have the files they are going to import located on shared network drives with really long pathnames. The application itself runs locally on their machine.

The odd behavior is as follows:

- When a file with the long path name located on a shared network drive is selected using the standard *browse* dialog, it is detected and processed fine.
- When the same file is dragged from explorer into application, no file is detected and nothing happens.

```java
public class DnDTest {

    @Start
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final VBox container = new VBox();
        final VBox dndZone = new VBox();
        final TextArea txtArea = new TextArea();
        final var bttn = new Button("Browse");
        dndZone.getChildren().add(new Label("Drop files here..."));

        dndZone.setPrefSize(200, 100);
        container.getChildren().addAll(dndZone, txtArea, bttn);
        container.setSpacing(10);

        dndZone.setOnDragDropped(evt -> {
            final var files = evt.getDragboard().getFiles();
            // Does NOT work. files is EMPTY
            if (files != null)
                txtArea.setText(getText(files));
        });

        dndZone.setOnDragOver(evt -> evt.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY));
        dndZone.setOnDragEntered(evt -> evt.consume());
        dndZone.setOnDragExited(evt -> evt.consume());

        bttn.setOnAction(evt -> {
            final var fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            final var files = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
            // WORKS for the same file.
            if (files != null)
                txtArea.setText(getText(files));
        });

        final Scene scene = new Scene(container);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.sizeToScene();
    }

    private String getText(final List<File> files) {
        return files
            .stream()
            .map(f -> f.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
    }
}
```

There are no problems with local files or with network files that have shorter path names. This problem appears when running on Windows 10 machines, but I don't know if it's limited to that OS.

Examples of some paths that cause issues are:

```
\\lab12jkd987.files.askon.ac.uk\Lab12Jkd987\Data\Microscopy\FixedCell\Joseph Diere\2022\2022_04_28_HMEC_FcRnGFPTransfected_FcRnAntagonists-AF555\2022_04_28_HMEC_FcRn-GFPTransfected_HAMsMediaOnly_1

\\lab12jkd987.files.askon.ac.uk\Lab12Jkd987\Data\Microscopy\FixedCell\Joseph Diere\2022\2022_04_13_BMDM_Dextran-AF555_JA01-AF647_Tf-AF488\2022_04_13_BMDM_Dextran-AF555p60c120_JA01-AF647p10c0_Tf-AF488p10c0-8

\\lab12jkd987.files.askon.ac.uk\Lab12Jkd987\Data\Microscopy\FixedCell\Joseph Diere\2022\2022_03_22 BMDM ReImaging_818C5+Mutants\2022_03_22 BMDM-M0_818C5-A647p10c0_JA03-A555p10c0_Tf488p10c0-9
```

Can anyone explain what is going on and how to get the behavior for the same file consistent between the two selection methods?

Comment: Create a local small text file with a name that exhibits the behavior you outline in your question.  Put the file content and the full file name in the question.  Also add a [mcve].  That way somebody could try to replicate your issue.  Without replication, you are unlikely to get any useful assistance.

Comment: @jewelsea I have added a minimal example in which this behavior can be reproduced, if someone can try this using files with long path names located on a shared network drive.

Comment: What is an example name that fails?

Comment: How long does the path name have to be before the problem occurs?

Comment: @jewelsea I have added some examples of filenames that were problematic

Comment: I tried your sample app on a macOS machine with a local filesystem using similar path setups to what you provided in your question.  Your issue did not replicate in that environment (which I guess is to be expected given your explanatory text).  I don't have a setup (Windows with a network share) to replicate your exact test environment, so unfortunately, I am unable to replicate your issue or assist.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for trying! Yes, I suspect this is something specific to Windows environments given the long history of pathname length limitations there.